# sfdx problem on wsl - CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory. UNC paths are not supported

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, cli, sfdx-error

I try try install SFDX on my WSL (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on WSL with Windows 10).
Looks like the version 7.119.2 has been installed, but when referencing sfdx, it doesn't hit the one installed on Linux, it just goes to windows (7.117.0). Do you have any idea, how to fix it?

```
mizio@K290:~$ npm install sfdx-cli -g
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@2.0.3: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
/home/mizio/.npm-global/bin/sfdx -> /home/mizio/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/sfdx-cli/bin/run
/home/mizio/.npm-global/bin/sf -> /home/mizio/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/sfdx-cli/bin/run-sf
npm WARN eslint-config-xo@0.36.0 requires a peer of eslint@>=7.20.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-config-xo-space@0.27.0 requires a peer of eslint@>=7.20.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-config-xo@0.35.0 requires a peer of eslint@>=7.20.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

+ sfdx-cli@7.119.2
updated 257 packages in 89.27s
mizio@K290:~$ sfdx --version
'\\wsl$\Ubuntu\home\mizio'
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
sfdx-cli/7.117.0 win32-x64 node-v14.17.6
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to install sfdx in a different way. After following the steps below, it started working:

1. Go to your home dir

   cd ~
2. Download TAR files

   wget https://developer.salesforce.com/media/salesforce-cli/sfdx/channels/stable/sfdx-linux-x64.tar.xz
3. Create the directory where you want to install Salesforce CLI.

   mkdir ~/sfdx
4. Unpack the contents for your TAR file

   tar xJf sfdx-linux-x64.tar.xz -C ~/sfdx --strip-components 1
5. Add to `~/.bashrc` file `export PATH=~/sfdx/bin:$PATH`